# how can I run remote Python(with jinja2) code

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to run a Python code on a remote machine using ssh. The Python code calls jinja2. I was able to run the code manually run the code and it works as expected, but when I tried to run it remotely via ssh, I am getting several errors.

Here is part of the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
import os
import shutil
import sys
from os.path import dirname
......
```

and the errors are:

```
from: too many arguments
python_code.py: line 3: import: command not found
pythno_code.py: line 4: import: command not found
python_code.py: line 5: import: command not found
from: too many arguments
......
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks,
Philip

Comment: Can you please add the command that you're using to launch python?

Comment: ssh remote-host "sudo su - remote-user ./python_code.py"

Comment: Check the location of appropritate python version installation in the machine and add it to shebang.

Comment: I have #!/usr/bin/python as the first line in the code.

Comment: deploy@remoe-host:~$ which python
/usr/bin/python

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by:

ssh remote-user@remote-host "./python_code.py"

for some reason ssh remote-host "sudo su - remote-user ./python_code.py" gave me the errors I saw before.